# how to display label in a view value coming from view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have got one label in view that i need to display value in that label and i have assigned value to that label in controller ..

and this is model

```
 namespace MvcSampleApplication.Models
 {    
     public class labelsdisplay
     {
        public string labelvalue { get; set; }    
     }
 }
```

and this is my controller

```
namespace MvcSampleApplication.Controllers
{
    public class LbelDisplayController : Controller
    {               
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            labelsdisplay lbldisx = new labelsdisplay();
            string name = "ABC";
            lbldisx.labelvalue = name;       
            return View(lbldisx);
        }    
    }
}
```

and this the view (strongly typed view)

```
 @model MvcSampleApplication.Models.labelsdisplay
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}    
<h2>Index</h2>
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{     
    @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.labelvalue)    
}
```

my problem is  not able to display value("ABC") instead of that it displaying "labelvalue"  in that label in view...
would any one pls suggest any solutions ...on this....

Many thanks..

Comment: Do you actually need a `label` element or you just want to display the value ?

Comment: I am not sure normally in web application we do use label but in mvc is there any other approach ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display just the value, you can use

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m=>m.labelvalue)
```

Or if you want to display the label element with value, you can use

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.labelvalue, Model.labelvalue)
```

The first param is the value of the name, and the 2nd param is the value of the label.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.labelvalue)
```

to

```
<label>@Model.labelvalue</label>
```

(or leave out the label tags, if you don't need them).

The @-operator will take whatever you give it and turn it into a string, HTML-encode that string (unless what you gave it was an IHtmlString) and render the encoded string in the output.

`Html.LabelFor`, on the other hand, is intended to be used with a form model. Let's say you have a model like this

```
public class PersonForm
{
  public string Firstname { get; set;}
  public string Lastname { get; set;}
}
```

and an action medthod accepting this form as an argument:

```
public ActionResult CreatePerson(PersonForm form){
  /* Create new person from form */
}
```

Now, in your view, to display a label for the `Firstname` field, you use `Html.LabelFor()`:

```
@model PersonForm

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Firstname)
```

This will render something like `<label for="Firstname">Firstname</label>`. If you instead wanted to render something like `<label for="Firstname">Please enter firstname</label>` you would attach an attribute to the `Firstname` property:

```
public class PersonForm
{
  [Display(Name = "Please enter firstname")]
  public string Firstname { get; set;}

  [Display(Name = "Please enter lastname")]
  public string Lastname { get; set;}
}
```

where the attributes are from the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace.